# Torsion-free affine connection under Geodesic normal coordinates is determined by curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesic, connections

I am reading Chern's Lectures on Differential Geometry. Chern proves the theorem that *A torsion-free affine connection is completely determined by the curvature tensor*,i.e. the **Theorem 2.3** on page 147 on
[this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wm8dQ9sHl4oC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=The+affine+connection+without+torsion+is+completely+determined+locally+by+the+curvature+tensor&source=bl&ots=2DFqxLrv_D&sig=ACfU3U2kRBb-ine6SI1KWlAz8Tl8t-vzVA&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp_cuy7K75AhUsD0QIHQNRBiAQ6AF6BAgiEAM#v=onepage&q=The%20affine%20connection%20without%20torsion%20is%20completely%20determined%20locally%20by%20the%20curvature%20tensor&f=false).

However, I can not understand (2.20) in that link, I copied what it states below. If we consider a normal coordinate system $\alpha^{i}$ at a fixed point $O$ and also choose a natural frame at $O$, then we get a frame field $e_{i}$ and its dual $\theta^{i}$. Let $\theta^{j}_{i}$ be the restriction of the everywhere linearly independent $m^{2}$ differential 1-forms,then we have
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\theta^{i} &=\overline{\theta}^{i}+\alpha^{i}dt\\
\theta^{j}_{i} &=\overline{\theta}^{j}_{i}
\end{align}\right.
$$
where the $\overline{\theta}^{i}$ and $\overline{\theta}^{j}_{i}$ means they do not contain $dt$

I can not see how this is derived, can anyone help me out?